# Copy/Paste not working in other apps when running Chart/PNG export Loop in Excel VB

Tags: vba, charts, excel, export

I have a loop that runs to generate a PNG (which is used in an HTML file).  While running, copy/paste does not work for other applications on the computer.  Is there a way to make copy/paste work within excel?  and/or speed up this code? (Some of this code I found elsewhere, and appreciate that help.)  Thanks.

```
Sub ToPNG()
    ' save a range from Excel as a picture
    Dim r As Range
    Dim c As ChartObject

    Const strPath As String = "C:\G\"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set r = Workbooks("GMon.xlsm").Worksheets("Main").Range("Print_Area")
    r.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

    Set c = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, r.Width + 0, r.Height + 7)
    c.Chart.Paste
    c.Chart.Export strPath & "GMonOut.png", "PNG"
    c.Delete

    ExitProc:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set c = Nothing
    Set r = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm confused, you want to do other copy/paste operations while this code is running? Can't it wait? You didn't say how long this code takes to run.

Comment: sorry, yes, I'm trying to copy/paste in other apps while excel is running in the background.  This loops every few seconds, so it can't wait.  The code itself takes a second or 2.  I guess it's not speeding up of the code that's needed.  It's more about system resources and if it's possible to make this copy/paste a local excel operation?

Comment: My guess is no, but I'm sure someone else will come along and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Since your code that is running "every few seconds" is using the clipboard, it will interfere with any other users of the clipboard.

The only option I see is to rewrite your code to avoid use of `Copy` `Paste` operations entirely.  (perhaps by automating the use of a 3rd party screen capture utility)